# Can I send a Notification Message each to Apple/Google to notify many devices?

Tags: android, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently using PushSharp library. I just wanted to make sure that whether Google GCM and Apple APNS supports to send my application's push notification request to many devices or I need to manually send push notification request for each device.

Answer (score 0):

For GCM You send just ONE message together with a list of registration ids (device identifiers) representing the devices you wish to receive the message. Thus it is much like sending an e-mail to many people, it goes to the server ONCE.

Comment: Don't know anything about ios, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For GCM, you send a request to Google's webservice and include an array of device IDs in the request. (With a maximum of 1000 IDs per request, if I'm not mistaking)

For APNS, you open a stream connection to the push servers and loop over all IDs while writing the IDs to the stream.

Comment: This means apple does not support this what GCM support, i mean send notification to multiple devices using a single request.

Comment: APNS doesn't work with a request, it works with a stream connection. This means: You open the connection, write the message, write the device IDs to which you would like to send the message, close the connection. Done.

Comment: You have to write the message for each of the device tokens separately. You can't write a single message with multiple device tokens.

Answer (score -1):

Dont know about GCM. But you need to check APNS services documentation for iOS

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Comment: Nothing in the documention about my question?